# AngularJS -> Query for "is at bottom of page"

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

What is the best way to ask "Is there more to scroll or have we reached the bottom of the scrollable area in Angular?"

Have a single page app with a fixed bottom navbar and want to display a ui cue indicating that there is more content to be displayed, conditional on not being at end of page.  Thinking there is a bookmark way (hash tag) to do this.

Comment: this is more jquery/dom related than angularJS related , at the end of the day , you'll have to write a directive for that.

Comment: wonder if scrollspy would work here as well

Comment: see also: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/scroll/README.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is kind of solution: I've created directive that bind scrolling event and in case of it is possible to scroll down it show div, appended in compile time:

```
app.directive('thereIsMore', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',    
    scope: true,
    compile: function(tElement) {
      tElement.append('<div class="there-is-more" ng-show="bottom">There is more...</div>');
      return function(scope, element) {
        var elm = element[0];        
        var check = function() {
          scope.bottom = !(elm.offsetHeight + elm.scrollTop >= elm.scrollHeight);
        };
        element.bind('scroll', function() {
          scope.$apply(check);          
        });
        check();        
        }; // end of link 
    }    
  };
});
```

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8W3E7BunpDxIkEPDqxzb?p=preview

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for, but unfortunately elm.scrollHeight is not accurately reported in several browsers on initial load.  It takes the scroll or resize event to update the true scrollHeight.  So it's not enough to provide an accurate indicator on initial load.  So bottom returns true until the user begins scrolling, but the most important time to show the cue is before the user scrolls (since cue is meant to get the user to scroll).  Not sure how to correct this (fails in Chrome, Chromium, IE).

Comment: I've updated plunker by adding some additional events: when window is resized and re-check of bottom after some timeout.

Comment: Looks like the timeout and window resize fixes the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: First issue => "Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!" happens over time ... I think it's because scope is being manipulated (and causing re-render which in turn retriggers the directive)... ultimately Angular complains about the infinite looping.

Comment: Second issue => When loaded via ng-view (routes), it takes a scroll action to be updated.  This means if I am viewing a long page and "more" is shown, and then I nav to a small page that is completely in view, more continues to show since I haven't scrolled.  Currently working around this by using $timeout to check every 250ms.

Comment: Try subscribing to $routeChangeSuccess event and call check there